# JavaFX: FXML: How to make the child to extend its size to fit the parent pane?

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I have managed to load a child fxml(sub UI) under a parent fxml (mainMenu UI).
I have created an AnchorPane with id "mainContent". This pane is bound to 4 sides and changes in accords to the stage.

The child window will be loaded into the "mainContent" anchorpane. However, I can't figure out how to make the child to change along with its parent "mainContent".

My child UI is called like this.

```
@FXML
private void mnuUserLevel_onClick(ActionEvent event) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DBedit.fxml"));
    loader.setController(new DBeditEntityUserlevel());

    try {
           Node n = (Node)loader.load();
           mainContent.getChildren().add(n);
    } catch (IOException e){
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To further illustrate my question, please see my snap shot. The red square is the child. The yellow square is the "mainContent" AnchorPane of the MainMenu parent.

[image]

Comment: This pane is bound to 4 sides and changes in accords to the stage.
How do you do this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you set the `static` methods `setTopAnchor( child, value )`, `setBottomAnchor( ... )`, `setLeftAnchor( ... )`, `setRightAnchor( ... )` of class `AnchorPane` to **0.0**, the child `Node` will get stretched to the full extend of the parent `AnchorPane`.

Documentation Link: [AnchorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html)

edit: in the documentation link you can also see how you can set these values in your java code.

FXML example:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="mainContent" ...>
<StackPane fx:id="subPane" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" ></StackPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Hi Sascha B, as a button is added. for example.                                                                                                   <AnchorPane fx:id="mainContent" ...>
<AnchorPane fx:id="mainContent" ...>
 <StackPane fx:id="subPane" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" >
  Button fx:id="button" layoutX="172.0" layoutY="195.0" onAction="#ingresarLogin" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="87.0" text="Ingresar" />
 </StackPane>
</AnchorPane>

it is correct??.........thanks

Comment: This accepted answer did not work for me.  It fills horizontally by not vertically.  Don't understand why such a simple concept is so hard to implement.

Comment: This doesn't do the right thing. The use case involves getting parent and ancestor `Node`s to adjust to their descendant `Node`s, not the other way round. See my answer.

Answer (score 33):

If you have a `Region`, which is a *subclass* of `Node` that includes `Axis`, `Chart`, `Control`, and `Pane` (this probably includes anything you might want to load), you can **bind** the child's size to the space in the parent similar to how they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12635224/1959155). Now any future adjustments of the parent's size will be reflected in the child.

```
Region n = (Region)loader.load();
mainContent.getChildren().add(n);
n.prefWidthProperty().bind(mainContent.widthProperty());
n.prefHeightProperty().bind(mainContent.heightProperty());
```

Comment: Dunno if this started with a more recent version of javafx but for me setting `prefWidth/Height` does nothing, I have to use minHeight.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working properly when using an anchorpane: when expanding the pane the child grows up to the new size and it's impossible to reduce the size back.

Answer (score 2):

With the look at the structure of your interface I guess you better use BorderPane as your parent container with this suggestion don't use AnchorPane directly inside the BorderPane container here is my suggestion you do:

->BorderPane-Top = "your menu"

->BorderPane-Center = another container (could be SplitPane, another BorderPane etc.. but not AnchorPane I guess but you can try if you want)

->BorderPane-Bottom = another container (could be hbox with buttons or label for info or notifications etc..)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the accepted answer is the right one. Setting the anchors in an `AnchorPane` does what it says in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html) (`setBottomAnchor`):

> If set, the anchorpane will maintain the child's size and position so
>   that its bottom is always offset by that amount from the anchorpane's
>   bottom content edge.

But that's not what is desired. It is to arrange things so that the child and parent are the same size.

The important thing to appreciate, from my experiments, is that a parent `Node` will accept and adapt to the width and height (preferred width? preferred height?) of its child/children... ***if you tell it to***. In other words, the mechanism works in the contrary direction to the one you might assume: the parent can be told to adapt to the child, not the child to the parent.

With an `HBox` containing a `ScrollPane` containing an `AnchorPane` containing a  `TextArea`, using SceneBuilder, this does what the question is looking for:

```
  <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
     <children>
        <ScrollPane prefHeight="100.0">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane>
                 <children>
                    <TextArea fx:id="logTextArea" prefWidth="800.0">
                    </TextArea>
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </ScrollPane>
     </children>
  </HBox>
```

Note that there is no use of anchors, and above all that the `ScrollPane` and the `AnchorPane` have no "preferred width" setting.

In SceneBuilder, the thing to adjust here for the `ScrollPane` and the `AnchorPane` is in the right-hand panel/concertina, under "Layout: ...:" choose the `ScrollPane`, and set "Pref Width" to "USE_COMPUTED_AREA". Then choose the `AnchorPane` and do the same. Finally, choose the `TextArea` and set this to your choice, e.g. in my case 800 (pixels). Obviously this setting can be adjusted to something more sophisticated in your code if you want.

You will then see that the parent `Node` of the `TextArea` (`AnchorPane`) and grandparent `Node` (`ScrollPane`) adjust to accommodate the `TextArea`.

Note that the `prefWidth` setting of the `HBox` then gets ***ignored***. It is the normal job of a container like an `HBox` to accommodate its descendants, and it would only be if you set its `maxWidth` to something incompatible with the requirements of its descendants that that constraint would then apply.

If you set a grandchild `Node` like this with a `prefWidth` of 800, I assume there is some way of calculating the width, under normal circumstances, of the grandparent `ScrollPane`: this will be something to do with settings of borders, padding, margins and the like, in all three components involved. Note the `protected` method in class `Region`, `computePrefWidth`, intended for subclasses to override, which may be of interest.

Plus, in the case of `ScrollPane`, the presence or absence of vertical and/or horizontal scrollbars, as and when these appear. If you set `wrapText` to `true` on the `TextArea` you might hope that a horizontal scrollbar will never appear. My experiments seem to show that you also need to set `ScrollPane`'s `fitToWidth` `Property` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with setting prefWidth. I don't know why, but it seems like it takes the prefWidth which is set in SceneBuilder after referencing your newPane to your AnchorPane.

```
Node newPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/YourPane.fxml"));
List<Node> parentChildren = ((Pane)yourAnchorPaneId.getParent()).getChildren();
parentChildren.set(parentChildren.indexOf(yourAnchorPaneId), newPane);
yourAnchorPaneId.setPrefWidth(1800); // 1800 just example value for test
Main.primaryStage.setWidth(500); // 500 example value with which you wishe to start app
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 :

```
// @FXML private AnchorPane pnlContainer;

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Demo.fxml"));

Node _node = loader.load();

_node.prefWidth(pnlContainer.widthProperty().doubleValue());
_node.prefHeight(pnlContainer.heightProperty().doubleValue());

// container child clear
pnlContainer.getChildren().clear();

// new container add
pnlContainer.getChildren().add(_node);
```

Alternative method;

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Demo.fxml"));

Node _node = loader.load();

AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(_node, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(_node, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(_node, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(_node, 0.0);

// container child clear
pnlContainer.getChildren().clear();

// new container add
pnlContainer.getChildren().add(_node);
```

Method 2 detail link : [JavaFX Panel inside Panel auto resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223812/javafx-panel-inside-panel-auto-resizing/15224445)