# Resizing SplitPane to fit AnchorPane parent

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

This might sound like a duplicate since there are tons of questions regarding resizing a child Pane to fit Parent Pane but I have tried almost everything without any luck.

My SplitPane is located inside an AnchorPane and this is my original code:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"  
    minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="792.0" prefWidth="1055.0" 
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
     fx:controller="com.judeochalifu.stock_manager.controller.NewSupplierController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="splitPlane" dividerPositions="0.5" layoutX="371.0" layoutY="229.0" prefHeight="792.0" prefWidth="1055.0"orientation="VERTICAL"  AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <items>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
    </items>
    </SplitPane>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the output without resizing:

[image]

When I drag the window to increase width or height, this is what I get:

[image]

The desired result is for the SplitPane to expend as the window expands, that is to resize according to the width and height of the Anchorpane.

Looking around I found these two questions where the OP is trying something similar:

[JavaFX: FXML: How to make the child to extend its size to fit the parent pane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270994/javafx-fxml-how-to-make-the-child-to-extend-its-size-to-fit-the-parent-pane)

[JavaFX Panel inside Panel autoresizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223812/javafx-panel-inside-panel-auto-resizing)

The answers suggest using only the attributes:

```
 AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
```

inside the child pane. I have tried this with no luck: This is what my code looks like now:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"  
         minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="792.0" prefWidth="1055.0" 
        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
   fx:controller="com.judeochalifu.stock_manager.controller.NewSupplierController">
     <children>
        <SplitPane fx:id="splitPlane" dividerPositions="0.5" "orientation="VERTICAL"  
           AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"  
           AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
           <items>
             <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" 
               prefWidth="160.0" />
             <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0"  
               prefWidth="160.0" />
           </items>
      </SplitPane>
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing the prefHeight, prefWidth of the inner anchore panes.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't compile your code because there are errors in it. There's a missing space between the `prefWidth` and `orientation` parameters in the first example, and unnecessary quotation mark right before the `orientation` parameter in the second example. After fixing them everything works as expected.

Here's the fixed code:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"  
            minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="792.0" prefWidth="1055.0" 
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.judeochalifu.stock_manager.controller.NewSupplierController">
    <children>
        <SplitPane fx:id="splitPlane" dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL"
                   AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
                   AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0"/>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0"/>
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note that you can specify `prefWidth`, `prefHeight`, `layoutX` and `layoutY` of your SplitPane, but since the anchors are set to 0, and it's the only child of the `AnchorPane`, it will always take all the available space so it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! I was searching for the same thing, but my setup is a little bit different. I used an outer scrollpane, and in that an anchorpane, and in that a splitpane, and in that an anchorpane that would stay small and hinder the splitspane from resizing. What I did to fix it was to select the SCROLLpane and set fit to width and fit to height to true. And also a couple of fit to parent.