# JavaFX BorderPane - apply constraints to the center size

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I have an BorderPane as the main layout. In the Center I have an AnchorPane that has a StackPane. Now on the StackPane I have some elements that extend Region. This elements can be moved with the mouse drag and drop.

My problem is that I can drag an element and drop it on the Bottom of the BorderPane and I don't want that. I want that this element to be "captive" in the StackPane or AnchorPane at least, so in the center of the BorderPane.

How can I do that? I tried to set the minSize of AnchorPane and StackPane to (0,0) and still didn't work.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223812/javafx-panel-inside-panel-auto-resizing but didn't help me to resolve this, just to align the anchorPane to the stackPane.

Comment: another thing that I found out, that helped me a little bit is that the order in fxml file matters for the BorderPane. So if I put center first then the other things will be on top. It's not the perfect fix, but for now works. This still doesn't make my elements "captive" in middle. Through "captive" I mean that the elements are visible in the center region and when I try to drag them out from this they are stuck in the center. Hope this is clear!